# Почему фон не растягивается на всю страницу?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Подскажите почему фон не растягивается на всю страницу?

```css
#main {
  background-image: url('../images/tires.png');
  color: #fff;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: relative;
  /* background-position: center center; */
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Здесь в коде вообще всего много. [Вот пример как можно сделать](http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/RWdvEN).

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  }
#main {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('http://sheridanhistory.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/tires.jpg');
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 color: #333;
 }
```

Comment: И что значит на всю страницу? растянуть блок по высоте? Если да, то в примере видно, что нужно указать высоту html и body.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы фон был ещё и адаптивным, как исправить?

Comment: Обновил пример и код. PS предупреждаю сразу, адаптивный бэкграунд очень проблематичная штука. Т.к. он вряд ли будет правильно покрывать 100% высоту блока.

Answer (score 1):

В Вашем `CSS` `background-size` указан дважды:

```
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
```

и

```
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

Выберите один вариант.
Второй - правильный.

Answer (score 0):

`background-size: cover;` или `backgound-size: 100% 100%`. Растягивает фон по Х и по У.